# How to adjust inparaenum-list (in particular line spacing)?

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, paralist

I really like the idea of working with `inparaenum`. It creates nice lists of numerated and tabbed math exercises. But how do I add line pitch option to this special paralist? I want to create more vertical between the two lines of exercises (a,b,c) and (d,e,f,).

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{enumitem}                                       
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1.)]
\item \textbf{Finit limits}: Calculate the following!

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{inparaenum}[a)]
\item $\lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) $ 
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 0} (x^2 + 3x - 4)$ 
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 2} (2x^2 + 5)^3  $
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x^5 - x^2 - 1 }$
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 4} \dfrac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15}$
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to a} A x^n$
\end{inparaenum} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you :)

**First modification**

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1.)]
\item \textbf{Finit limits}: Calculate the following!

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{inparaenum}[a)]
\baselineskip2.5\baselineskip
\item $\lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) $ 
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 0} (x^2 + 3x - 4)$ 
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 2} (2x^2 + 5)^3  $
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x^5 - x^2 - 1 }$
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 4} \dfrac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15}$
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to a} A x^n$
\end{inparaenum} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\baselineskip2.5\baselineskip` moves my equation-lines. But this yields too much distance above the equation (best would be only distance between equations) and it somehow freaks out on the exercise f).

Comment: Which pitch? Where? Where?

Comment: Between the first math-line (a/b/c) and second line (d/e/f). The vertical space.

Comment: your code is not working, please edit it. You can try `\baselineskip5\baselineskip` inside `inparaenum` and leave blank line in the end.

Comment: You don't need `enumerate` package and I don't know if you really need `enumitem` but it cause problem in your code delete it make your code working (after adding \end{enumerate})

Comment: Maybe \usepackage{enumitem} and \usepackage{enumerate} could be left out, for me this MWE is running. \baselineskip2\baselineskip is a good idea though :) but unfortunately this changes the vertical distance above the first line too. Is there further modification on baselineskip2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an all-in-one solution using `tasks`. Time to use modern packages. I have defined two environments for clarity.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{que}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[que,1]{label=\arabic*.),ref=\arabic*.)}

\usepackage[more]{tasks}


\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[a]),label-width=1em,item-indent = 0.5em,column-sep =2em]{exer}[\exercise](3)

\begin{document}
\begin{que}
\item  \textbf{Finit limits}: Calculate the following\par
\begin{exer}
\exercise $\lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) $
\exercise $\lim_{x \to 0} (x^2 + 3x - 4)$
\exercise $\lim_{x \to 2} (2x^2 + 5)^3  $
\exercise $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x^5 - x^2 - 1 }$
\exercise $\lim_{x \to 4} \dfrac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15}$
\exercise $\lim_{x \to a} A x^n$
\end{exer}
\end{que}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here you can use `after-item-skip =` key to adjust the skip between rows. The default value is `1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex`.

Comment: The points are defined after the parathesis :) This looks very good. I will try to implement it (got many problem with loading the new package task..)

Comment: Why does this always start with 6.) and how can I change this?

Comment: @Mac: I didn't notice it, sorry. Looks like a bug where one can't nest `tasks`. I have now used `enumitem` for the outer enumerate. Please see the update.

Answer (score 4):

What about this? I added some vertical spacing at the beginning of `inparaenum`, with the `etoolbox` package. Don't forget a blank line:

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}
%\usepackage[shortlabels, inline]{enumitem}%usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{inparaenum}{\addtolength{\baselineskip}{2ex}\vspace*{-2ex}}

\AtEndEnvironment{inparaenum}{\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1.)]
\item \textbf{Finite limits}: Calculate the following!


\NumTabs{3}
\begin{inparaenum}[a)]
\item $\lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) $
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 0} (x^2 + 3x - 4)$
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 2} (2x^2 + 5)^3 $
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x^5 - x^2 - 1 }$
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to 4} \dfrac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15}$
\tab \item $\lim_{x \to a} A x^n$%\tab
\end{inparaenum}

\item\textbf{Infinite limits}: Calculate the following!
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]